# xamarin android native library - No Packages Found

Tags: android, xamarin, java-native-interface

A few days ago I was able to create an android bindings library for a particular .jar without issue.

I attempted to make a new library in order to post a question sample on github, now JarToXml won't generate anything:

```
1>JARTOXML : warning J2X9001: Couldn't load class device/scanner/ScanConst :  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: device.scanner.ScanConst
1>JARTOXML : warning J2X9001: Couldn't load class device/scanner/ScannerService : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: device.scanner.ScannerService
.... (Same error for all classes in .Jar)

1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8601: No packages found.
```

I'm totally confused because in one project I can generate the bindings, yet in another I can't.

Jar file: https://github.com/mribbons/PM_Scanner/blob/master/device.scanner.jar?raw=true

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was the path of the 2nd binding library project - Java doesn't like #.